# convert byte text( type is string) to string in python

Tags: python, string, byte, encode

I have a string like this: `s = "b'1f\xe6\xb5\x8b\xe7\xbb\x98'"`

How to convert it back to the original string?

I try to use `eval(s)`, however get `SyntaxError: bytes can only contain ASCII literal characters.`

Comment: Have you tried decoding `s` using `s.decode('utf-8')`?

Comment: If a string prints as `"b'1f\xe6\xb5\x8b\xe7\xbb\x98'"`, you have to double the backslashes if you're trying to test it in console: `eval("b'1f\\xe6\\xb5\\x8b\\xe7\\xbb\\x98'").decode('utf-8')` gives a possibly useful result. The problem is that your original is just a fragment, so you get something like `'1f测绘'`, where `1f` is an orphan of cut-and-paste or something. How did you end up with that string? It would be better to take it closer to the source where it was less mangled.

Comment: @Gsk I'll rather upvote FHTMitchell :)

Comment: It's just a test text file encoded with Huffman Coding. I convert all text to byte to get them coded. And I want to decode it. `"b'1f\xe6\xb5\x8b\xe7\xbb\x98'"` is the decoded result which is the byte formatted text of original text '1f测绘'.

Comment: No, `b'1f\xe6\xb5\x8b\xe7\xbb\x98'` is. In your question, it is additionally wrapped in a string, which complicates everything unnecessarily. If you just have the bytes, you wouldn't need to evaluate the string first.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `eval`, it's dangerous. Use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) instead and then decode to a string like @Amadan says:

```
import ast
s = r"b'1f\xe6\xb5\x8b\xe7\xbb\x98'"
res = ast.literal_eval(s).decode()
print(res)  # --> '1f测绘'
```

---

As is said in the comments, my `s` actually has a  `repr` that looks like `"b'1f\\xe6\\xb5\\x8b\\xe7\\xbb\\x98'"`. Can you please confirm what your `print(repr(your_string))` and `print(your_string)` look like?

Comment: Thank you very much! I confirm that `s = "b'1f\xe6\xb5\x8b\xe7\xbb\x98'"` is what I got.